# Login required error in google youtube api for ratings

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube-api

I am working with getting the rating of youtube video using the code google provide to use within website. Here is the code

```
function videosGetRating(params) {

      gapi.client.setApiKey('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
                gapi.client.load('youtube', 'v3', function() {
                         params = removeEmptyParams(params); 
  var request = gapi.client.youtube.videos.getRating(params);
  executeRequest(request);
                });

}

$('#idlikes').click(function(){

    videosGetRating({'id': '6M6W2lbkuiw',
                 'onBehalfOfContentOwner': ''});
    });
```

But I am getting the error

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Login Required",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Login Required"
 }
}
```

I donot why its ask for authentication but  gapi.client.setApiKey need api key only. If I am not wrong this error come when oauth2 access token is not pass to api key. But there is no option to add oauth2 access token in this code.

Comment: `videos.getRating` returns the rating (like or dislike) a single user has given the video. Hence, authorization via OAuth is required. If you want to get the total number of likes and dislikes for a video, use the `videos.list` endpoint with `part=statistics`. This can be done with an API key.

Comment: Yes I want to get if single user like or dislike video. and please if you know how to authorize the user for this code? @paolo

Comment: [This guide](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/client-side-web-apps) explains how to use the JS client library to authorize with OAuth.

Comment: I follow these steps but still same output @paolo

Comment: There's no use posting your videosGetRating(params) method when you haven't even been able to Login. Show your login code as you were not able to pass that part.

Answer (score 0):

The sample in [JavaScript Youtube Code Samples](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/javascript#search_by_keyword) is enough to get you through this Login problem.

Here are the steps to run the sample:

1. In your Google Dev Console, make sure Youtube API is enabled.
2. Generate an OAuth clientID for Web not an API Key. You will not use API Keys here.
3. Copy the codes for auth.js (it's mentioned in the sample docs) and save it in your text editor as `auth.js`
4. Copy the codes for playlist_updates.js and save it in your editor as `playlist_updates.js`
5. Copy the codes for playlist_updates.html and save it in your editor as `playlist_updates.html`
6. Place this three files in one folder.

> ```
> youtube_sample --
>                --auth.js
>                --playlist_updates.js
>                --playlist_updates.html
> ```

7. Place the generated OAuth ClientID in your `auth.js`. You'll find where to place it there in `var OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID = '__YOUR_CLIENT_ID__';`
8. Now everything is set. Start a local server and run it. I use `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000`

***Note***

When generating OauthclientID that you'll run in localhost 8000 (or whatever port you specify), set it up in your Google Dev Console like:

- Authorised JavaScript origins: `http://localhost:8000`
- Authorised redirect URIs: `http://localhost:8000/oauth2callback`

I was able to run the sample:

[image]

Now you can play with the Youtube methods and other features. You should have no problem logging in now.